# Why does the Perforce Visual Studio plugin run "p4 changes -s pending -l" before every check in

Tags: visual-studio-2008, perforce

Whenever I check a file in to my Perforce depot using the Perforce plugin for Visual Studio (p4scc) there is a significant delay before the "Submit Changelist" dialog box appears (sometimes up to a minute).

In the log file (enabled with "Enable logging to file" in the plugin Preferences) there's an entry`"p4 changes -s pending -l"`.  This command downloads all the pending changelists, which in our environment numbers a few hundred thousand.  (I guess the plugin is doing this to be able to give me a list of other pending changelists which I might want to move the files to.)

Is there any way to prevent the plugin doing this ?

I am using P4V version 2009.1/212209 in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: We have 150,000 pending CLs, and I'm seeing the same problem with P4V on OSX. This problem is more general than the p4scc plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is *no*. Sorry. If it really is slowing things down e-mail *support@perforce.com* and report it as a bug (or at least question why it does it as there could be a good reason why).

IMHO the better workflow is to always have *P4V* open and submit changelist from there. In P4V it is easier to check/diff each file, break up the changes into atomic changelists, and write more detailed submit notes than 'fixed bugs'.

Use *P4SCC* for the integration with Visual Studio, e.g. to automatically check files out when you edit them and marking files for add.